# limitation of array_agg in Postgresql 9.1

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

When using array_agg or array_string, the array returns empty above a certain size.

`SELECT array_agg(x.id) FROM (SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 500) x` - this works and returns an array.

but this query : `SELECT array_agg(x.id) FROM (SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 667) x`
Doesn't work. it returns an empty array.

i'm pretty sure this doesn't reach the limitation size of an array. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no. try `SELECT array_agg(x.id)
    FROM (SELECT * FROM cast(generate_series(1,1158) as int)as id)  x`

Comment: I found out what was the issue. the limitation is in the display environment. `pgAdmin III` doesn't display the data in the UI, but it's there.

Comment: @Ereli When the timer permits you to, please add that as an answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the issue here was not Postgresql, but rather the client I was using.
`pgAdmin III` doesn't display the content of array over a certain size. about 4.5k.
when using `psql` one doesn't encounter the same issue.

the the UI of `pgAdmin` there is an option to set ["Max characters per column"](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/options-tab4.html) and it was set to 256 in my case, which makes little sense.
but you copy & paste the array that looks empty into notepad you'll find the all the data is there.